# React Native state issue, State not updating when i setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a function that **setState** and navigates to a new section. The problem I am having is that the **state variable** is not updating with what I set it as. I'm considering using **flushSync**, I know I can use a **UseEffect** and run my function whenever the State Variable changes. Are there any **alternatives** I can use?

I tried using a **useEffect** and use the **state variable** as a dependency.

Comment: if you want proper help share your code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.